# Two wires induced-EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there an induced-EMF from two wires being close to each other (d = 1mm)? I'm assuming since each wire has its own magnetic field. Only in the beginning when current starts to flow and then stabilizes?

A diagram:

[image]

Comment: Do not confuse current induction and force between current currying conductors

Comment: It's called magnetic induction. Change in current in one wire produces a change in mag field and this induces a voltage in the other wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only yes, but any time the current in one wire changes, it will affect the other.  This is the basis of crosstalk, as well as a transformer, and even a transmission line.